# Digital signals - multiplication of Bits ( number of bits ) - How to do it? ( binary bits )

Tags: adder, binary, bit-rate

Let us say I have a number with p bits:
`x = [___...___] >> p` Bits.
and I want to multiply it by another p bits.
will I receive:
`x = = = [___...___...___] >> 2p` Bits.
or:
`x = = = [___...___...___] >> 2p-2` Bits.

EDIT:
trying to explain better:
let us say I have a variable $X$.
x = some binary with has length of p bits ( if p=2, then X can be 00,01,10,11 ).
and I want to multiply the length of the bits of X ( p ) by another p.
Will I receive a variable x = 2p or x = 2p-2 ( and as said, length of 2p or 2p-2 )

Comment: What does '>>' signify; is that supposed to be a right shift? Are your numbers signed or unsigned? Please try to clean up the formatting of your question. It is very confusing as written.

Comment: the >> is not for right shift, just means that X has 2p bits ( amount ). I dont know how to explain it very much, but all I mean, if the length of X in binary, will be 2p bits or 2p-2 bits, if I multiply X by another p bit

Comment: Try some worst-case examples. What do you get if you multiply the largest 3-bit number by itself? Does the result need 6 bits or just 4 bits?

Comment: Oh It gave me 6 bits. I see. Thank you, didnt think of it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For unsigned binary numbers with \$p\$ bits, the largest positive number is equal to \$2^p -1\$. Multiplying two such values together gives a product equal to \$2^{2p} - 2^{p+1} + 1\$. Since the largest exponent of \$2\$ is \$2p\$ we will need \$2p\$ bits to represent the product.

For example, suppose \$p=3\$. The largest possible value is 7, and the largest possible product is 49 (\$2^6 - 2^4 + 1 = 64 - 16 + 1 = 49\$). In binary, \$49 = 110001\$, which takes 6 bits.

Comment: Great! you even proved it for me :)